# Why i need to call two time to call() for work?

Tags: web3js

I am trying to use the attribute `allowed` like this

```
await contract.methods.allowed.call()
```

that does not worked, but if i use this code worked fine

```
await contract.methods.allowed.call().call()
```

Comment: Can you show the contract code for the `allowed` method? How is the variable contract initialized? Is it a truffle contract or a web3js contract?

Comment: @Ismael i am using web3js

Comment: @Ismael can you help me please with https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/115552/why-when-i-used-sendtransaction-i-got-contract-deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call is missing the parenthesis `()` after the function name.

```
let allowance = await contract.methods.allowed().call();
```

Check the web3js documentation for [how to call contract's methods](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call).

Comment: can you help me with this please https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/115552/why-when-i-used-sendtransaction-i-got-contract-deployment