# Why when i used sendTransaction i got contract deployment?

Tags: web3js

i need to do a transaction, i was trying with two methods, send and sendTransaction

this is my code with send:

```
await contract.methods.pulse(tId).send({ from: accounts[0] })
```

in this case i got in my metamask: contract interaction

but if i use sendTransaction

```
return await web3.eth
      .sendTransaction({ from: accounts[0], data: contract.methods     .pulse(tId).encodeABI() })
```

i got contract deployment.
[image]

what is happening here, which one is fine, what is the difference?
what does mean contract deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the "to" parameter

```
web3.eth
  .sendTransaction({ 
    from: accounts[0], 
    to: contract. options.address,
    data: contract.methods.pulse(tId).encodeABI(), 
  })
```

Comment: why should i use sendTransaction? sendTransaction is better than send?

Comment: sendTransaction() is better than send()?

Comment: @react1 It is the same, `contract.method.pulse().send()` uses `web3.eth.sendTransaction` underneath. In general using `contract.method.pulse().send()` is easier.

Comment: can you help me with this please https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/115684/how-can-i-fund-to-my-coinbase-account

Comment: @react1 Sorry, but I've never used coinbase.

Comment: help me please with this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/116998/how-can-i-show-the-icons-to-connect-my-wallet-from-my-mobile