# How can i show the icons to connect my wallet from my mobile?

Tags: web3js, metamask, coinbase

My code works very well on desktop, but when i tried on mobile (open console for developers click on cellphone and reload) does not appear the buttons to connect to metamask or fortmatik, or coinbase

```
function init() {

  const providerOptions = {
    walletconnect: {
      package: WalletConnectProvider,
      options: {
        // Mikko's test key - don't copy as your mileage may vary
        infuraId: "8043bb2cf99347b1bfadfb233c5325c0",
      }
    },

    fortmatic: {
      package: Fortmatic,
      options: {
        // Mikko's TESTNET api key
        key: "pk_test_391E26A3B43A3350"
      }
    }
  };

  web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
    cacheProvider: false, // optional
    providerOptions, // required
  });

}
```

you can try here:  https://codepen.io/polats/embed/dyGXPOz?theme-id=dark&default-tab=js,result&embed-version=2

how can i show the icons for connect in mobiles?

these icons i can not see in mobile just metamask:

[image]

i was figure out in the console, i have this userOptions (from cellphone)
[image]

from desktop

[image]

Comment: this is the same error https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal/issues/331